Extract RGB values from image once automated colorbar is applied
I would like to save the RGB values that are automatically generated by matplotlib when I display a simple 7x7 matrix using imshow
The only way I have figured out is to save the displayed image, then use imread to extract the colors of the saved image (code below).
plt.imsave('matrix.png',correlation,vmin=-1,vmax=1)
colors = plt.imread('matrix.png')
There has to be a better way to do this, right?

See How can I generate a colormap array from a simple array.  norm = plt.Normalize(vmin=-1, vmax=1); colors = plt.cm.viridis(norm(correlation))

Note that if you have the AxesImage object (im = ax.imshow(...)), you can just do im.to_rgba(data). And if you didn't even create the image yourself, you can get the AxesImage object with im = ax.get_images()[0].
